# How many times the output statement is excuted in this fragement?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

The fragment is

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=n-1;j>=i;j--)
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
```

My answer is that for 1st of `i`, `i=0`, and the inner loop `(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--)` will be executed n times, and for the 2nd of `i`, `i=1`,the inner loop will be executed n-1 times. And for the (n-1)nd times of `i`, `i=n-2`, the inner loop will be executed 2 times, and for the last of `i`, `i=n-1`, so the inner loop will be executed 1 times.

Add them together `n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+2+1=n(n+1)/2`.

But the textbook's answer is `n(n-1)/2`, so what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Work it out for `n=1` and see what happens.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your second loop. I guess that should be `for(int j=n-1;j>=i;j--)`

Comment: Other than that syntax error, you're right. It IS n(n+1)/2. For 10, it will be performed 55 times; you can verify your answer with a simple counter.

Comment: Perhaps the textbook is wrong. It happens. Check to see if you can find a list of errata online. If you cannot, then you should submit the error to the publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically printing every combination of 2 numbers from 1 to n without importance of order and with repeats (same element can be chosen twice).

There are `C(n,2) + n = n!/((n-2)!2!) + n = n(n-1)/2 + n = n(n+1)/2` such possibiities, where `n` is the number of elements.

- C(n,2) - choose 2 elements out of n without repeats
- n - all possible duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your textbook's code isn't

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=n-1;j>i;j--)
    ...
```

This would give you `(n-1)n/2` as per its answer.

If not, and your code is exactly as the book, then you are correct - you are just selecting all possible pairs with replacement, so it is `(n+1)n/2`

Comment: I double check with the textbook, I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: His code has `j>=i`, your code has `j>i`. Add `n` for cases where `i=j` and you get the same asnwer.

Comment: @amit. That is exactly my point. If the textbook has `j>i` and not `j>=i` then it will be `(n-1)n/2`. If it has the `>=` form then the OP is right and the book is wrong.